# Check If Thread Is on Gui Context

Tags: c#, wpf

How can I check if the current running thread is on the GUI context or not?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's unfortunately hard to answer this question with 100% accuracy because it's not always entirely obvious what constitutes a GUI Context. It's more of a heuristic than a yes / no answer. And the heuristic will be different for every GUI framework.

For WPF a good one is to check and see if there as an active `Dispatcher` for the current thread

```
public static bool IsWpfGuiThread() {
  return Dispatcher.FromThread(Thread.CurrentThread) != null;
}
```

However this can be fooled by just setting up a `Dispatcher` on a random thread but not actually putting a GUI on top of it.

For WinForms a good one to check is the current `SynchronizationContext`.

```
public static bool IsWinFormsGuiThread() {
  return SynchronizationContext.Current is WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext;
}
```

However this can be fooled by someone temporarily (or longer) resetting the `Current` value to another synchronization context.  This is essentially just a global thread and can be set by anyone. It's actually fairly common for it to change in certain applications like Visual Studio (but that's a WPF app though)

Comment: I know this is an old answer, but... there can be multiple UI threads in a WPF app, checking for an active dispatcher on the current thread using [Dispatcher.FromThread()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.fromthread(v=vs.110).aspx) is not a good indicator that it is a (or "the") UI thread. One of the best ways to handle this is to keep track of the SynchronizationContext of the thread that initiates a long running or background thread, this is where the async/await can be helpful (not that they existed when this answer was first written).

Answer (score 1):

Are you asking if you have a known gui object can you query it to see if you are in the proper context of that object? I think `guiObject.VerifyAccess()` will work for this.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want the `Dispatcher` object.  See http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/wpf/thread/360540eb-d756-4434-86f9-a3449f05eb55